# how to untar a file in python when the name of the file keep changing?

Tags: python, file

I'm a beginner so sorry If I'm a little vague with the question.

I have a perl script that runs and generates a tar file. I am trying to write a python script that untars the file. The only issue is the file name changes everytime the script is run.

```
filename = name-month-day-year-hour-minute-seconds.tar.gz(eg filename = final-06-23-2018-11-40-32.tar.gz)
```

I am trying to find way(probably regex) to untar the file in my python script because the file name will always change anytime i run the script because of the date and time added. I tried `tar -xvf final*` on the command line and that works but that does not seem to work when i do `tarfile.open(final*, r:gz)` in the python script. Any help?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob.glob()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) to search for files using wildcards:

```
files = glob.glob('/tmp/*.tar.gz')
for file in files:
    tarfile.open(file, r:gz)
```